# Switch subtypes

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have following example structure of classes:

```
public class Base
{
}

public class Child1 : Base
{
}

public class Child2 : Base
{
}
```

And I want to do some black magic:

```
Base @base = new Child2(); //note: there @base is declared as Base while actual type is `Child2`
var child1 = (Child1) @base;
```

And it fails with `System.InvalidCastException` as expected.

Then I added implicit cast operator to `Child2`:

```
public class Child2 : Base
{
    public static implicit operator Child1(Child2 child2)
    {
        return new Child1();
    }
}
```

And code still throws the same exception (explicit operator also does not help).

Do you have any ideas how to fix this behavior without using `dynamic`, custom cast method or declaring local variable `@base` as `Child2`?

Comment: Well, you explicitly cast the object. So define an explicit operator, instead of implicit.

Answer (score 2):

You've implemented an implicit cast in Child2,
but are trying to cast from Base, actually.

You should first cast it to Child2 so the implicit conversion to Child1 will apply:

```
var child1 = (Child1)(Child2)base;
```

OR

```
Child1 child1 = (Child2)base;
```

And if you don't know the type:

```
var child1 = base is Child1 ? (Child1)base : (Child1)(Child2)base;
var child2 = base is Child2 ? (Child2)base : (Child2)(Child1)base;
```

A completely different approach would be:

```
public class Base
{
    public T As<T>() where T : Base, new()
    {
        return this as T ?? new T();
    }
}
```

But anyway - this is bad design and you shouldn't, in general, have stuff like that.

I suggest posting your actual need, the thing you are trying to do, with all the details, and ask for a better design/solution.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I have no idea what is actual type of @base.

Comment: @hazzik See edit. Also, you can have that logic implemented into implicit casts inside Base, to both Child1 and Child2, if both should logically have implicit casts between one another. That way you can cast Child2 to Child1, Child1 to Child2, Base to Child1, Base to Child2, and obviously Child1/2 to Base.

Comment: *Either move the implicit cast operator to Base* is not possible (argument or return type must be of type "Base") + conversion to derived classs... BAM

Comment: @YoryeNathan I could not define cast operators inside base class - compiller rises an error: user-defined conversions to or from a derived class are not allowed

Comment: @YoryeNathan actually I was trying to solve a porblem https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2845 where Child2 is a BaseProxy object and Child1 is user defined type. I found the best possible solution for NHibernate (in my comment to the issue) but I want to know if it possible to solve the issue in general.

Comment: You're right, you can't implement the operator in Base. But the second option is still valid.

Comment: @hazzik See edit for different solution. Anyway, you can always implement implicit casts in both and then performing the `is` check like in the 3rd piece of code.